# Interchange limit of one variable with partial derivative of another variable

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Consider a function $f(t,y)$ where $t,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is given that $ f(t,y)$ is continuous   but $\dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial t}$ suffers a jump at at $t= x$. (The function $f$ could describe the temperature field in a composite region where different metal strips are glued together at $t=x$ )

How can I then show that  $\dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y}$ is continuous at $t=x$ ?

**My attempt**:

We need to show
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow x^{-}} \dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y} =  \lim_{t \rightarrow x^{+}} \dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y}$$
This is equivalent to showing
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow x^{-}} \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h} =  \lim_{t \rightarrow x^{+}} \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h}$$

Q) Now is there some hypothesis on $f(t,y)$ or $\dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y}$ that will allow me to interchange the order of limits ?

If so, then it is enough to show
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \lim_{t \rightarrow x^{-}} \dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h} =  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \lim_{t \rightarrow x^{+}} \dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h}$$

By continuity of $f(t,.)$ at $t=x$,

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow x^{-}} \dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h} =  \lim_{t \rightarrow x^{+}} \dfrac{ f(t,y+h) - f(t, y)}{h} = \dfrac{ f(x,y+h) - f(x, y)}{h}$$
which proves what I want.

So my question is exactly what hypothesis/theorem is necessary to permit the interchange of limits here ?

Comment: It is sufficient to show $\lim_{t\to x}\dfrac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial f (x,y)}{\partial y}$

Comment: @Reasoner: Yes, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have not clearly stated what the  assumptions with respect to ${\partial\over\partial y}$ are. The function $f(t,y):=|y|$ satisfies your assumptions, but $f_y$ is not continuous, resp., undefined at $y=0$.

One possible setup could be the following:
$$f_t(t,y)=\cases{g_>(t,y)\quad&$(t>0)$ \cr
g_<(t,y)\quad&$(t<0)$\cr}$$
with $g_>$, $g_<\in C^1$ in a full neighborhood of $(0,0)$; furthermore we assume that $\phi(y):=f(0,y)$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Then one has
$$f(t,y)=\cases{f(0,y)+\int_0^t g_>(s,y)\>ds\quad&$(t\geq0)$ \cr
f(0,y)+\int_0^t g_<(s,y)\>ds\quad&$(t\leq0)$\cr}\ ,$$
and it becomes obvious that $f_y\in C^1$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: Could you explain if the assumptions you made about the functions lead to the permissible interchange of limits  I describe in the question ? WhenI asked the question, I thought I would need some kind of uniform continuity or boundedness to allow the interchange, but I could not find any theorem that applies.